# Adding enum type to a list

Tags: java, enums

If I need to add an enum attribute to a list, how do I declare the list? Let us say the enum class is:

```
public enum Country{ USA, CANADA; }
```

I want to do:

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
l.add(Country.USA);
```

What needs to be used instead of `List<String>?`

Comment: added Java tag, remove it if I'm wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the string type use this:

`l.add(Country.USA.name());`

otherwise the answer of MByD

Comment: Why not l.add(Country.USA.toString())

Answer (score 10):

Should be:

```
List<Country> l = new ArrayList<Country>();
l.add(Country.USA); // That one's for you Code Monkey :)
```

Comment: would it be different for C#? just curious

Comment: +1 but you are missing the second part, the addition of the enum value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hold *any* enum, use this:

```
List<? extends Enum<?>> list = new ArrayList<Country>();
Enum<?> someEnumValue = list.get(0); // Elements can be assigned to Enum<?>
System.out.println(someEnumValue.name()); // You can now access enum methods
```

Comment: You can't add elements to a `List<? extends Enum<?>>`. Better use `List<Enum<?>>` for this.

Comment: @Paulo good point, but then you can't assign: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<MyEnumClass> to List<Enum<?>>`. Maybe this idea isn't useful here :(

Comment: Of course, you would use `new ArrayList<Enum<?>>()`. An `ArrayList<MyEnumClass>` can't contain anything which is not an MyEnumClass object (without violating type-safety).