# java enum ArrayList - is this possible?

Tags: java, enums

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding enum type to a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969841/adding-enum-type-to-a-list)

I have an enum class:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ONE, TWO, THREE;
}
```

And in another class, MyClass.java, I want to have the following

```
ArrayList<MyEnum> list;
```

is this possible? because I'm encountering some issues.

Comment: If you describe your issues, you might get something better than "yes, that works."

Comment: You might want to define what "some issues" are :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There should be no problem doing that.

This code compiles fine:

```
package example; 

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Example {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        List<MyEnum> enums = new ArrayList<MyEnum>();
    }

    enum MyEnum { ONE, TWO, THREE;}
    //         no need for that  ^ but added to match your question
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. but what about if the enum is a seperate class?

Comment: It doesn't matter, if it is in a different package though, you will need to import it.

Answer (score 4):

Despite "*some issues*" you have, aren't you actually looking for an [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html)?

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> set = EnumSet.of(MyEnum.ONE, MyEnum.THREE);
```