# how do you make an arraylist of different enums?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have tried looking for the answer for quite a bit of time , so can anyone help me ?

Thank you in advance.

@MehdiB. I have no clue of where to start.

@Bohemian so I am building this game which needs certain requirements to unlock certain items. and I would like to store these requirements in an array which has different

something like this :
ArrayList requirements = new ArrayList();

requirements.add(Weapon.AK47);
requirements.add(House.Mansion);

Comment: Please provide more details, some code and what you've tried so far.

Comment: This sounds like a [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), what are you trying to achieve with this list of enum constants?

Comment: see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969898/180100)

Comment: What do you hope to do with a list of enum of different types?

Comment: @MehdiB. I have no clue of where to start.

Comment: Thanks for the accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the following example:

```
enum E1 { e1 };
enum E2 { e2 };

public  class Test <E extends Enum> {
  List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();

  void add(E e) { list.add(e); } 
  void dump() { System.out.println(list); }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Test<Enum> test = new Test<>();
    test.add(E1.e1);
    test.add(E2.e2);
    test.dump();    
  }
}
```

You can declare a list to accept "any enum"; and as any enum class **must** be derived from Enum, you can then use that specific class to instantiate a Test that allows to add enum constants coming from enum classes.

Of course, this is more of a "code puzzle"; as I would regard such a design with a lot of caution; not something that I would do in "real world production" code.

Answer (score 0):

Use Arraylist with Object type elements and cast to whatever enums you wanna use when you use them

Comment: You can do [better than that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969898/256196)