# Add different enum classes to a list

Tags: java, list, class, arraylist, enums

Lets say I have the below enums declared

```
public class Enums{
    public enum A{
        a1,
        a2;
    }
    public enum B{
        b1,
        b2;
    }
    public enum C{
        c1,
        c2;
    }
}
```

Now I want to pass a1,b1 and c1 to a constructor while creation of object

```
Course c = new Course(a1,b1,c1);
```

How can pass these values like a list instead of typing all the enums. Can I do as below?

```
List<Enums> eValues = new ArrayList<Enums>();
eValues.add(A.valueOf("a1"));
eValues.add(B.value("b1"));
eValues.add(C.value("c1"));

//and then can I do as below?

Course c = new Course(eValues);
```

I am getting an error "no suitable method found for add(A)" while adding elements to list

Code on the Constructor side:

```
public <T extends Enum<T>>Course(T[] eValues){
//some processing using those enums
}
```

Need help on how to add enums to a list and send it while object creation? and if possible how to receive them in the constructor

Answer (score 1):

None of this works. `A` is not an `Enums` - the fact that `A` is declared inside `Enums` does not mean: `Enums x = A.a1;` is legal. Try it. Enums can implement interfaces; they cannot extend classes.

You can have a method or constructor that accepts any number of values, using varargs. Generics are irrelevant here; generics serve to link things together, they are not a solution for dynamic typing. Just the basic java typing system itself does that; e.g. `Number n = foo();` lets you assign an Integer, a Double, a Float, or some custom number type you made in your own project to `n`, there is no need to bring generics into it. Generics is only useful if you want to write a method and you want to express for example: "Param 1 is some type, and param 2 is a list whose components are guaranteed to be the same type" - you want a generics term to show up in at least 2 places or it's useless.

At best you're looking a something like:

```
public interface CourseValue {}

public enum A implements CourseValue { A1, A2; }
public enum B implements CourseValue { B1, B2; }
public enum C implements CourseValue { B1, C2; }

public class Course {
  private List<CourseValue> values;
  public Course(CourseValue... courses) {
    values = List.copyOf(courses);
  }
}

...

new Course(Enums.A.A1, Enums.B.B2);
```

If you use java 17+ you can 'seal' the interface (make it so that only explicitly listed types, e.g. A B and C, can implement it).

Answer (score 0):

In your third code block from the top, Java doesn't know where enums `A`, `B`, or `C` are. Since these are static enums *within* a class, you need to reference them using the class first.

`Enums.A a1 = Enums.A.valueOf("a1");`

As for the constructor of your Course class, you've went a little overboard on your implementation. You're trying to parameterize your Course object to a type of enum. As far as I can tell, you should only be concerned with the parameters in the constructor, not the method itself. You can pass in a list parameterized to the wildcard `?` or parameterize it to accept an `Object`:

```
public Course(List<Object> enumsList) {
   // Do what you need to with your enum list.
}
```

See: [how do you make an arraylist of different enums?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43170409/how-do-you-make-an-arraylist-of-different-enums)